# How effectively join ruby hashes recieved from json lists

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting, hash

I'm trying to make page with table which content is data from two arrays.
I have two lists(arrays) with hashes:

```
arr1 = [ 
         { "device"=>100, "phone"=>"12345" }, 
         ..., 
         { "device"=>102, "phone"=>"12346" } 
       ]


arr2 = [ 
         { "device"=>100, "type"=>"mobile", "name"=>"nokia" }, 
         ..., 
         { "device"=>102, "type"=>"VIOP", "name"=>"smth" } 
       ]
```

How can I join hashes from arr1 and arr2 by "device" to get a result array:

```
result = [ 
           { "device"=>100, "phone"=>"12345", "type"=>"mobile", "name"=>"nokia" }, 
           ..., 
           { "device"=>102, "phone"=>"12346", "type"=>"VIOP", "name"=>"smth" } 
         ]
```

Page which consist table with result array, loads very slowly and I need to find the fastest way to generate result_array.

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
(arr1 + arr2).group_by { |i| i["device"] }.map { |d,(i1,i2)| i1.merge(i2)}
#=> [{"device"=>100, "phone"=>"12345", "type"=>"mobile", "name"=>"nokia"}, {"device"=>102, "phone"=>"12346", "type"=>"VIOP", "name"=>"smth"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to tackle it. Here is a quite readable way to do it:

```
# prepare an index hash for easier access of data by device
first_by_device = arr1.group_by {|a| a['device'] }

# build a new array joining both data hashes for each item
result = arr2.map do |item|
  device = item['device']
  item.merge first_by_device(device)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(arr1 + arr2).group_by { |i| i["device"] }.values.map{|x|x.reduce(&:merge)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the prettiest one, but it works:

```
result = arr1.collect{|a| h = arr2.select{|b| b["device"] ==
a["device"]}.first; h ? a.merge(h) : a }
```

Do you need something faster for large amount of data?

```
h = Hash.new
arr1.each do |a|
  h[ a["device" ] ] ||= Hash.new
  h[ a["device" ] ].merge!(a)
end
arr2.each do |a|
  h[ a["device" ] ] ||= Hash.new
  h[ a["device" ] ].merge!(a)
end
result = h.values
```